# Twisted set cache headers

Tags: python, caching, twisted

How would one set appropriate cache headers on a `GET` request? I want to set `expires` and `cache-control` as you'll see below:

My `render_GET` looks similar to this:

```
def render_GET(self, request):
    data = self.getData(request) #dict
    cache(request)
    request.write(json.dumps(data))
    request.finish()
```

I wrote the following cache helper:

```
from wsgiref.handlers import format_date_time as format_date
from datetime import date, timedelta
from time import mktime

'''
   Sets the cache headers for a (static resource) request
'''
def cache(request, expires=30, public=True):
    #set expires header
    expiry = (date.today() + timedelta(expires)).timetuple()
    request.setHeader("expires" , format_date(mktime(expiry)))

    cache_control = "max-age=" + str(60*60*24*expires)
    if public:
        cache_control += ", public"
    else:
        cache_control += ", private"
    request.setHeader("cache-control", cache_control)

    return request
```

However the resulting response headers aren't as expected:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 12 Mar 2014 13:03:04 GMT
Server: TwistedWeb/13.1.0
transfer-encoding: chunked
```

Here's the [actual intended usage](https://gist.github.com/megawac/597e8827d4f57c6955fd)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your gist and your question, your gist has the `cache` after writing

```
 request.write(qjson.dumps(lang))
 cache(request)
 request.finish()
```

where as the question has `cache` before write.

```
def render_GET(self, request):
    data = self.getData(request) #dict
    cache(request)
    request.write(json.dumps(data))
    request.finish()
```

Most likely, your question's code would work but your gist would not. But as pointed out in the comments, this is not the issue.

You did not set the `Content-Length` header. If you do not set a `Content-Length` header, chunked encoding is used which disables cache headers.

The following produces the right response headers

```
def render_GET(self, request):
    data = json.dumps(self.getData(request)) #dict
    request.setHeader('Content-Length', len(data))
    cache(request)
    request.write(data)
    request.finish()
```

Inspired by the following post http://msoulier.wordpress.com/2010/06/11/twisted-python-and-chunked-encoding/

Comment: Going to try this later, found another solution as well

Answer (score -1):

Based on [this bug report](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/4897) on TwistedMatrix I switched `request.setHeader()` to `request.responseHeaders.setRawHeaders()` as below:

```
def cache(request, expires=30, public=True):
    #set expires header
    expiry = (date.today() + timedelta(expires)).timetuple()
    request.responseHeaders.setRawHeaders("expires" , [format_date(mktime(expiry))])

    #set cache control
    cache_control = "max-age=" + str(int(60*60*24*expires))
    if public:
        cache_control += ", public"
    else:
        cache_control += ", private"
    request.responseHeaders.setRawHeaders("cache-control", [cache_control])

    return request
```

Results in the headers being served:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=2592000, public
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-length: 0
Date: Wed, 12 Mar 2014 16:18:57 GMT
Expires: Fri, 11 Apr 2014 00:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 12 Mar 2014 15:06:01 GMT
Server: TwistedWeb/13.1.0
```

Comment: @downvoter I don't have much experience with Twisted whats wrong with my soln? I'm getting the 304 responses and headers I wanted